# How to label clothes?

Tags: clothing

What can I do to label clothes and make then distinguishable? My brother recently started copying my style and started buying same clothes, now here's the real problem. We wear same cloth sizes so it's completely same looking. Now the problem is obvious, I thought of UV markers but I don't want to look silly in some places with UV lights such as some clubs or whatever. So how to label clothes to make them distinguishable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my kids I used an initial written in permanent marker on the existing label. It won't work for socks, but should do for everything else.

A friend handled the socks issue by embroidering a small heart or star (just a few stitches) somewhere inconspicuous. She didn't use initials in case other kids noticed and teased them.

Answer (score 2):

Standard procedure in dorms or camps: either indelible pen or marker, or sewn-in labels. Just put the label in an out-of-sight location such as waist-band or collar. If you find your label on his apparel, you've collared the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

I make a "V" cut on the label. I used to write my initial with a permanent marker, but sometimes they're not that "permanent"

Answer (score 1):

Use inner side of cloths to mark the cloths so it will not be see and can also be used to identify before wearing it.
personally I do make a little cut to the existing company labels(if they are external to cloths) and that helps me to identify my cloths.